# How to print dictionary values without dict

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{
    'name': 'Camila Cabello',
    'follower_count': 49,
    'description': 'Musician',
    'country': 'Cuba'
},
```

I have this dictionary.
if I type `print(B.values())`
it prints this

```
dict_values(['Camila Cabello', 49, 'Musician', 'Cuba'])
```

I only need to print this

```
'Camila Cabello', 49, 'Musician', 'Cuba'
```

Comment: try `print(list(B.values()))` for starters

Comment: What you expect looks like a literal representation (including quotes around string values), but not really one that makes sense (it's not a list and not really a tuple either). I could understand `Camila Cabello, 49, Musician, Cuba`. Please clarify what you want to do with this expected value.

Comment: If you just want to print this for debugging or as very simple yet "cleaner" program output: `print(*B.values(), sep=', ')`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(*B.values(), sep=', ')
AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Uhm, no, you're doing something wrong there. You appear to be calling `.values()` on what you got back from `.values()`…

Comment: @deceze yes I need to print without [] braces like this 'Camila Cabello', 49, 'Musician', 'Cuba'

Comment: Why "need"? For what purpose? Or is it just "want", without specific purpose?

Comment: learning purpose

Comment: @deceze print(*B.values(), sep=', ') it works bro thank you very much

Comment: previously I mistake

Comment: i typed B = B.values then type this print(*B.values(), sep=', ')

Comment: @deceze bro please help one more time. I need to print values but not 49 Camila Cabello', 49, 'Musician', 'Cuba'. I need to hide follower_count

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 `dict.values()` returns a `dict_values` object. Printing it as is prints a "complex" string representation.

Converting to `list` would do:

```
>>> print(list(d.values()))
['Camila Cabello', 49, 'Musician', 'Cuba']
```

For a better control of delimiters, just join the *representation* of the values

```
>>> print(', '.join(repr(x) for x in d.values()))
'Camila Cabello', 49, 'Musician', 'Cuba'
```

Comment: While this does answer the question as given, I'm not sure how much sense it makes to do this. It's hardly a string you'd want to present to a user, and it's a useless format for anything else…

Comment: added the list method which is at least parsable back to a list by ast.literal_eval

Comment: I'd hope you wouldn't want to *parse* this back at all, just *output* it for presentational purposes…?!

Comment: just showing how to go in a deeper level to print representation of single elements, that's it. The quoting isn't a bad idea if the strings contain quotes.